# Arrows in Polar Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot the phasors of the voltage across the resistor, capacitor, and inductor in an series R-L-C circuit. I have done all of the calculations and I can get a decent plot with just the normal `ax.plot(theta,r,....)`.

I would like to make the phasor vectors look like arrows. I have been trying to use `ax.arrow(0,0,theta,magnitude)` but it looks like a line still. The gist to the code that I have written is here : [GIST](https://gist.github.com/Jesse-Millwood/aecb27116e8a8aac3d1d)

My image that I create is [image]

I tried to follow the example that I found on [this list](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Arrows-in-polar-plot-at-zero-degree-td23866.html) because it is very similar to what I want to accomplish, it produces the following image:

[image]

When I run their code on my computer I get

[image]

I am on Xubuntu 14.04 and running matplotlib 1.3.1. I do see that the example I am using was using matplotlib 0.99 in 2009.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow sizes were too big, this:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print "matplotlib.__version__   = ", matplotlib.__version__
print "matplotlib.get_backend() = ", matplotlib.get_backend()


# radar green, solid grid lines
plt.rc('grid', color='#316931', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=15)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=15)

# force square figure and square axes looks better for polar, IMO
width, height = matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize']
size = min(width, height)
# make a square figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(size, size))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True, axisbg='#d5de9c')

r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
theta = 2*np.pi*r
ax.plot(theta, r, color='#ee8d18', lw=3)
ax.set_rmax(2.0)
plt.grid(True)

ax.set_title("And there was much rejoicing!", fontsize=20)
#This is the line I added:
arr1 = plt.arrow(0, 0.5, 0, 1, alpha = 0.5, width = 0.015,
                 edgecolor = 'black', facecolor = 'green', lw = 2, zorder = 5)

# arrow at 45 degree
arr2 = plt.arrow(45/180.*np.pi, 0.5, 0, 1, alpha = 0.5, width = 0.015,
                 edgecolor = 'black', facecolor = 'green', lw = 2, zorder = 5)

plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Better? :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I see that now for the width and it worked for me but I would like to apply this to my Phasor Diagram now. I have this for my phasor vector: 

`ax.arrow(LV.theta[1],0,0,LV.mag[1], width=0.005,length_includes_head=True,edgecolor = 'black', facecolor = 'green', lw = 2, zorder = 5)`

The diagram now looks like this[Diagram](http://imgur.com/yZNDMIc)

Comment: I realized now it was the `head_length` attribute I was not setting properly