# Phasor Diagrams (vector plots) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, plot, polar-coordinates

I have phasor information (polar vector data pairs, each with magnitude and angle, representing voltage and current measurements) that I would like to display using Javascript. They should look something like the image linked below (my rep isn't high enough to directly post it) which I stole from [Jesse's question about MatPlotLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982107/arrows-in-polar-matplotlib-plot). I would also like to easily change which phasors are displayed by a simple mechanic like clicking on the legend entry.

[See a phasor diagram example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVOdC.png).

While I have inspected several code sets, I have yet to find a chart package that is built to handle polar vectors like this. Is my Google-fu lacking or do I need to create everything from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like this is a cheap workaround, but here's what I ended up doing:

I used the [polar chart from jqWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm#demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_polar_series.htm) and with the **series type** set to "column" and the **flip** property switched to "true." I put the data in an array with 0 entries for each possible angle except for where I wanted the phasor displayed. Each phasor gets a dedicated series so the legend lists them all. It's not perfect and the array is much larger than it really should need to be, but it's passable.

While it's not surprising that no power system display package is publicly available for Javascript, I'm sure one has to be out there for educational sites if nothing else.