# Use python to make a plot of bearings

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot up 5 bearings all taken from the same position. They are all in this format
1,306,22,44.0
2,223,20,36.0
with 1 and 2 representing the order they were measured in. Then it is degrees, arc minutes and arc seconds (ddd,mm.ss.s). 
I initially thought it would be just a matter of plotting a circle with lines spreading out at the appropriate angles. Unfortunately I have now spent all day looking at polar plots, compass plots, quivers etc and now I am really confused on how to approach this. Can I plot in ddd,mm.ss.s or do I need to convert them to decimal degrees or radians. If so do I use something like pandas. Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This: "or do I need to convert them to decimal degrees or radians". Have you tried that? Then  use a polar plot with arrows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arrows in Polar Matplotlib Plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982107/arrows-in-polar-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: Thanks Evert, I have progressed some. I can now actually make a plot of the data but I fear that I have complicated it by using a polar plot. I also need to work on the calculation in the DataFrame as the conversion from degree, minutes, seconds to decimal degrees is not correct. I would add the code but I am not sure how to do that at the moment. Need to work on that one as well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the transformation of degrees, minutes, seconds to decimal degrees. In the file containing the data I had to add .0 to each of the minute values. It then transformed correctly.